# How to get index of same elements in an array..?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to find the index of elements of my array using,

```
int[] arr = { 10, 20, 10 };
for ( int i; i,arr.length; i++)
{
int Tempval = arr[i];
index = Array.IndexOf(arr, Tempval);
console.writeline(index);
}
```

But its returning the same index for 10 i.e. 0 everytime.
How can I control it..??
Please help.

Regards

Comment: Looks like a syntax error in your statement: for ( int i; i,arr.length; i++)

Comment: It's not clear what you *want* the results to be... and the code you've given wouldn't even compile. Please post your expected output and *real* code.

Comment: I want an output as
0,1,2. But its returning 0,1,0.
My real code
           int index;
            int[] arr = { 10, 20, 10 };
                for ( int i=0 ; i <= arr.Length-1; i++)
                {
                int Tempval = arr[i];
                index = Array.IndexOf(arr, Tempval);
                Console.WriteLine(index);
                Console.ReadLine();
                }

Comment: @user2345759, you said index of same elements in the array, it should be `0,2` not `0,1,2` what exactly you need ?

Comment: I mean to say index of repeating elements.
If array hold element 10,20,10.
I am trying to take there indexes, bt my code is giving output 0,1,0.
I want the output as 0,1,2.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
int[] arr = { 10, 20, 10 };
for ( int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
int Tempval = arr[i];
index = Array.IndexOf(arr, Tempval);
console.writeline(index);
}
```

Comment: I want an output as 0,1,2. But its returning 0,1,0

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ you can do:

```
int[] arr = { 10, 20, 10 };
var result =
              arr.Select((r, index) => new { Value = r, Index = index })
             .GroupBy(item => item.Value)
             .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
             .Select(r => new { Indexes = r.Select(t => t.Index).ToArray() })
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

For output:

```
foreach (var value in result.Indexes)
    Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Output would be:

```
0
2
```

Comment: Why output 0,1,2 ? `20` is not duplicate (Same) in the array then why ?

Comment: My requirement is to sort indexes of array size,
I have done that, but when there are same elements in an array, its always returning an index of first element.

Comment: @user2345759 isn't that answered already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352721/sort-an-array-and-return-index-of-arrays-according-to-elements-size-in-c-sharp ?

Answer (score -2):

You are already using loop and i is your index, why find index again?

```
int[] arr = { 10, 20, 10 };
for ( int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
 int Tempval = arr[i];
 index = Array.IndexOf(arr, Tempval);
 console.writeline(i);
}
```

If you want all the indexes,

```
        public IEnumerable<int> FindIndexes(int[] array, int value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                int Tempval = array[i];
                if (Tempval == value)
                {
                    yield return i;
                }
            }
        }
```

and call `FindIndexes(arr, 10);`

Comment: This wouldn't compile, in various ways.