# Why are array indices repeating after an interval?

Tags: c#, sorting

I am trying to use selection sort in my code, and return the indexes of my array after sorting it, but my program is not giving the result as I want.

```
int kick=0;
int[] array = new int[10] { 100, 50, 20, 40, 10, 60, 80, 70, 90, 30 };
int[] index = new int[array.Length];

Console.WriteLine("The array before Selection Sort is: ");
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("array[" + i + "] = " + array[i]);
}

int tmp, min_key;

for (int j = 0; j < array.Length - 1; j++)
{
    min_key = j;
    for (int k = j+1 ; k < array.Length; k++)
    {
        if (array[k] < array[min_key])
        {
            min_key = k;
        }

    }
    int min = min_key;
    index[kick] = min;
    tmp = array[min_key];
    array[min_key] = array[j];
    array[j] = tmp;
    kick = kick + 1;
}

Console.WriteLine("The array index after Selection Sort is: ");
for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("index[" + i + "] = " + index[i]);        
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

The out put I am getting is

```
4
2
9
3
9
5
7
7
8
0
```

My question is why are indices repeating?
Why are 9 and 7 coming again? I don't want them again.

You can run and execute my code in console application.

Comment: Your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352721/sort-an-array-and-return-index-of-arrays-according-to-elements-size-in-c-sharp

Comment: My for loop will return index of array.
I have copied the output as well,
This is the exact code, you can copy this code in c# console application, and run.
I am new in programing so cant get an idea why is it happening, why is my result coming with repeated values.

Comment: @I4V That's not OP's answer, it's someone else's :) The OP is clearly after completing a learning exercise (and a very good exercise at that) not after the most compact way of doing it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I know, just to show that 4 questions about the same topic is too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this does not work is that you are swapping the actual items, rather than swapping the indexes. The smallest item is initially at the index 4, then at index 2, then at index 9. At this point you swap 50 and 30, so 50 ends up at index 9. Then you find 40 item at index 3, and then you find 50 - again, at index 9. That's why the indexes repeat.

To fix this, change the algorithm to initialize `index[i] = i` for the entire range, and then change the algorithm to compare

```
array[index[k]] < array[index[min_key]]
```

Do not write to `index` at all (i.e. you do not need the `kick` index). Instead of swapping `array[min_key]` and `array[j]`, swap `index[min_key]` and `index[j]`. This should take care of the problem: all items of the `array` would remain in place, only indexes would get sorted.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was so confused.

Comment: this means I should not swap the elements..
only the indexes..??

Comment: @user2345759 Yes, you should swap only the indexes, and compare elements using indexes, as above. This is a very common thing to do when objects being sorted are too large, making it expensive to move them around.

Comment: Yes, I have been practicing it.
I have done it your way,
I am only swapping the indexes, now its working efficiently.
Thanks for your precious advises.
Its been a very good learning for me.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the index instead of the sorted values? If you need the index, just swap it like you did with the values.

```
int kick = 0;
int[] array = new int[10] { 100, 50, 20, 40, 10, 60, 80, 70, 90, 30 };
int[] index = new int[array.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++)
{
       index[i] = i;
}

Console.WriteLine("The array before Selection Sort is: ");
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("array[" + i + "] = " + array[i]);
}

int tmp, min_key;

for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
{
    min_key = j;

    for (int k = j + 1; k < array.Length; k++)
    {
        if (array[k] < array[min_key])
        {
            min_key = k;
        }
    }
    tmp = array[min_key];
    array[min_key] = array[j];
    array[j] = tmp;

    tmp = index[min_key];
    index[min_key] = index[j];
    index[j] = tmp;
 }

  Console.WriteLine("The array index after Selection Sort is: ");
 for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("index[" + i + "] = " + index[i] + "(" + array[i] + ")");

 }
 Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
I was swapping the elements.